# Trouble with iCloud signing request

Tags: icloud

How can I keep my iPad from asking me to log in to iCloud?
I don't want anything to do with iCloud and I don't want to be constantly hounded by Apple to log in.

Comment: Having an iDevice & not wanting any connection to iCloud is a bit like having a car but not wanting it to need petrol

Answer (score 1):

Try under `Settings` > `iCloud` > `Sign Out` at the bottom of the page. You shouldn't be prompted for a password again until you sign in under the same menu.

---

### Edit 1

Not sure whether that's exactly what you meant, but I cannot seem to recall Apple asking for a log in when no data is entered under the iCloud tab.